# F#: Attributes on discriminated union fields?

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

I can do this:

```
type AttrAttribute () =
    inherit Attribute ()

type MyDU =
    | [<Attr>]A of bool
    | [<Attr>]B of int * string
    | [<Attr>]C of byte * char * int64
```

... but is there any way to do this?

```
type MyDU =
    | A of [<Attr>]bool
    | B of int * [<Attr>]string
    | C of [<Attr>]byte * char * [<Attr>]int64
```

Apparently, the case values are just fields (e.g. `let v = B (13, "oops") in (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (v, v.GetType ()) |> fst).GetFields ()`), so I'm hoping this is doable, somehow.

Comment: I tried naming the DU fields as well as putting paretheses in a few places, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Right, I'd tried naming them as well.  "Anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration."  Sounds like a bogus error.

Comment: I've tried doing this before and I couldn't find a way either. This might be a good proposal for https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions.

Comment: @Tarmil, wouldn't it make more sense to submit the proposal to someone at Microsoft, since attributes are specifically a .NET feature?

Comment: No, this is specifically an F# issue. As far as .NET is concerned, these are fields, so it is possible to put attributes on them; the only thing lacking is that there is no syntax in F# for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite contrived:

```
type A_ = { [<Attr>] Item1 : int }
type B_ = { [<Attr>] Item1 : int; [<Attr>] Item2 : string }

type MyDU =
    | A of A_
    | B of B_
```

And

```
let v = A({Item1 = 1})
let record = ((FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (v, v.GetType ()) |> fst).GetFields ()) |> Array.head 
let attrs = record.PropertyType.GetProperties() |> Array.collect(fun p -> p.GetCustomAttributes(false))
```

Comment: That's just decorating properties of records.  It's an OK work-aorund, but binding DU values would be less straightforward, and pattern matching them would be more verbose/complicated.

Comment: @MiloDC it's the only workaround I can think of, since F# doesn't support said syntax.

Comment: Why don't you solve it with a wrapping type and implicit operators?

Comment: Coming up with a work-around wasn't an issue; I had done that before posting my question (by leveraging the applicability of my attribute to each union case).  I simply wanted to know if it was possible to decorate the fields of a union case.